# Deployed but no translation occurring 17.multilingual-conversations

Tags: node.js, botframework

so I'm having an issue where my bot runs after 'npm start' I write anything and then it asks me "Choose Your Language:" with the "es" or "en" options. I choose the 'es' for Spanish and then it responds in English "Your current language code is: es" after that it repeatedly asks me "Choose Your Language:". So my question is what might I perhaps be doing wrong? Also, shouldn't the statement "Your current language code is: es" be in Spanish after choosing? Am I perhaps adding the translation keys in the incorrect location (I put it in the .env file)? PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still not seeing a translation after adding the key to your .env file, try adding the key to the application settings of your bot on azure:

[image]